# Why does the length of an array have to have a negative next to it when doing the outer loop

Tags: python, range, bubble-sort

```
def sort(nums):
  for i in range(len(nums)-1,0,-1):
    for j in range(i):
      if nums[j]>nums[j+1]:
        temp = nums[j]
        nums[j] = nums[j+1]
        nums[j+1] = temp
```

nums = [5,3,8,6,7,2]
sort(nums)
print(nums)

I am a beginner in python and i am learning bubble sort my question is what is the effect of putting -1 next to len(nums).

Comment: You have 2 options: Go from the last item to the first one OR go from the first item to the last one. 
First option means going down. 
Second option means going up. 

And the length of an array and the postions are counted different. 
the length of this array ["a","b"] is "2". 
But it  has only the postions 0 (first position) and 1 (second position). 
To get the last item, you can now perform len(array)-1  = 2-1 = 1  
and array[1] = b

Answer (score 0):

The [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) takes three arguments, where the first argument is the first number in the sequence.

The first index you iterate over is the last element in the list, hence you use `len(nums)-1` so you get the valid index of the last item in `nums` list, as indexes are zero-based in Python.

e.g.

```
nums       = [5,3,8,6,7,2] 
length     = len(nums)  # 6
last_index = length - 1 # 5
```